# Android - Strange bug or something wrong with my file structure?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-studio

After today's work on my Android app, this started happening:

**1:** Android Studio say that the ID: welldana_image isn't there, even though it's right above: (*Image below*)

[image]

^ This problem persists all the way through this `.xml` file (`activity_calculate_mine.xml`)

**2:** The two project "show package" types aren't matching. In the first picture (*Android style*), the layout file `activity_calculate_mine.xml` isn't there, but in the second (*Package style*) picture, it is. (*Pictures below*)

[image: Layout file isn't there]

[image: Layout file IS there]

***EDIT:*** Everything works fine. I just don't want to push this to the marketplace, and suddenly it won't work. But everything works fine at the moment, though seeing these errors.

***EDIT 2:*** Now this has happened? Is there an error in my manifest that I can't spot?

[image]

***EDIT 3:*** Luckily I saved myself a copy of the project before everything went nuts. Apparently I deleted the `activity_calculate_mine.xml`. I solved this problem by simply placing the old version in the same directory as of before, and then just copy pasting the `activity_calculate_mine.xml` back into it's original placement.

Problem solved. Thank you.

Comment: After doing what Philipp suggested, also reboot your computer. Android Studio can be funny at times.

Comment: @milez Tried rebooting my computer before posting this question as I know Android Studio has a life on it's own, but the problem still persists

Comment: Thats good, but reboot again after removing the plus signs from where they dont belong. Also clean & build anew.

Comment: @milez Still no change. Could someone explain why Android Studio creates the `+` if it's not necessary? It does the same in all other `xml` files, which btw have the same problem now.

Comment: It might be because the resource ids are not set. Try cleaning your project and make sure you don't have any syntax or whatsoever problem in your resource files, otherwise they won't be compiled.

Comment: @BarışcanKayaoğlu Did that already, and it still compiles fine. there is no syntax errors. I haven't changed anything since yesterday where everything worked perfect. (Note: it STILL works fine, I just don't like red text)

Comment: I recently changed the directory of the project. I suppose that is the problem?

Comment: Well it shouldn't be a problem if it compiles fine. Meaning that you can build up a R.java file.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "+" sign in the line android:layout_below="@+id..."
The @+id defines an id value, the @id referes to one.

Change this:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/welldana_image"
```

To this:

```
android:layout_below="@id/welldana_image"
```

Comment: No change what so ever. It's still "red"

Comment: Clean your project after that. That answer should fix your problem.